# Search if program is installed for a particular purpose (Linux)

Tags: linux, man

So, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 and I wonder if there is a program for opening PDF-files installed. I find that evince is installed in the system (by googling), and I stop to think if this can be done within Linux instead.

Using a terminal.

```
man -k PDF
```

Which does not print evince, since -k searches the NAME section in all the manuals, and the text does not mention "PDF".
Fortunately, Ubuntu 12.04.4 comes with man version 2.6.1 which has the option -K --global-apropos.

```
man -K PDF
```

gives a list mentioning evince + a a lot more files since the -K forces the search to be in all the sections in the manuals.

evince is just an example. And in hindsight a better keyword is "viewer".

How shall one (in the most effective way) find what programs are installed in a Linux system that match certain keywords?

Is there another way than man (or apropos)?

Comment: It's more appropriate be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
dpkg --get-selections